# Saving the order of an element among its siblings when deserializing

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have an XML document on the form

```
<element>
   <aaa></aaa>
   <bbb></bbb>
   <aaa></aaa>
</element>
```

that I'm deserializing to a POJO using JAXB.

```
public class Pojo {
   List<Aaa> aaaList;
   List<Bbb> bbbList;
}
```

Despite the fact that the `aaa` and `bbb` elements end up in two different lists I want to later be able to find out which order they were originally in.

Is it possible to save the order of the original `aaa` and `bbb` elements among their siblings when deserializing the XML? In other words, is there any way to create a field `int order` on the `Aaa` and `Bbb` classes that will automatically contain `1` for the first `aaa`, `2` for the first `bbb` and `3` for the first `aaa`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could include a field in your classes `Aaa` and `Bbb` that indicates the position of the element in the xml as the xml is traversed during unmarshalling like:

```
public class Aaa
{
   int position;

   public int getPosition()
   {
      return position;
   }

   public void setPosition( int position )
   {
      this.position = position;
   }
}
```

Similarly do it in the class `Bbb.java`.

Now set a listener to your unmarshaller like :

```
jaxbUnmarshaller.setListener(new Listener()
{
     private int position = 0;
     @Override
     public void beforeUnmarshal(Object target, Object parent) 
     {
         if ( target instanceof Aaa )
         {
             position++;
             Aaa aaa = (Aaa)target;
             aaa.setPosition( position );
         }
         else if ( target instanceof Bbb )
         {
             position++;
             Bbb bbb = (Bbb)target;
             bbb.setPosition( position );
         }

     }
});
```

As JAXB unmarshalls the xml, the listener gets called and sets a position of the element in your `Aaa` and `Bbb` objects. You can retrieve them using `getPosition()` on them.

The following code will print the positions of the `aaa` and `bbb` tags.

```
Elements data = (Elements) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal( file );
List<Aaa> aaas = data.getAaa();

for ( Aaa aaa : aaas )
{
    System.out.println( "aaa" + " " + aaa.getPosition() );
}
List<Bbb> bbbs = data.getBbb();
for ( Bbb bbb : bbbs )
{
    System.out.println( "bbb" + " " + bbb.getPosition() );
}
```

Output :

```
aaa 1
aaa 3
bbb 2
```